# Rails server returning error with Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, gemfile, method-missing

When I run my rails server on Terminal, I get the following message:

```
Exiting
/Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for Install (call 'Install.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/app/models/install.rb:4:in `<class:Install>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/app/models/install.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise.rb:291:in `get'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:81:in `to'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:76:in `modules'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:93:in `routes'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:160:in `default_used_route'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:70:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise.rb:325:in `new'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise.rb:325:in `add_mapping'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:238:in `block in devise_for'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:237:in `each'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:237:in `devise_for'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.0/bin/spring:51:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.6.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Rushal-Marketing/Desktop/pinter/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.1'    

gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.3'



group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end



gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'spring'
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Any assistance with this would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command

```
 rails generate devise:install
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in your console

```
bundle install
```

Then

```
bundle exec rails generate devise:install
bundle exec rails generate device model_name
```

in your case `model_name` might be `Install`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to bundle your gems:

```
bundle install
```

Then you have to install devise:

```
rails g devise:install
```

And then you have to restart the rails server:

```
Ctrl + C
$ rails s
```